# Not able to invoke alexa skill in smartphone while it is working in echo dot with same account

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I have an alexa skill which was previously working fine in smartphone and echo dot with same account in developer mode. I went ahead with distribution and added beta testers and enabled beta testing. Now I'm not able to invoke this skill from my smartphone while it is working in echo dot, both linked to my developer account. Also none of the beta testers are able to invoke the skill even after enabling it. Any idea what might be the problem here?

Comment: This kind of problem usually happens when we have a different locale, so let's say if you're in India so try using Indian language because sometimes Alexa doesn't understand the utterance in en-US language.

This is pretty common, and the best practice to this is to use Indian Locale for it.

Comment: I'm using Indian locale itself. It was working as expected previously also. Now when I go to alexa.amazon.com and take your skills under dev, there is a tag in my skill as 'devUS'. Does this mean that it can only be used in US locale? If yes how to change that?

Answer (score 0):

There is a locale discrepancy between your skill, your account, and your Alexa App. In order to use a skill, the skill's language model must match the user's account location as well as the app's location.

This means on one account, you will only be able to see and test skills from one marketplace at a time. So, if you've got your developer account configured for the US, and your skill only has a en-IN language model, you won't be able to see and test it in your Alexa app.

There are two options available to fix this issue:

-Option 1-
The simplest solution is to create a new language tab for your skill within developer portal that matches the language setting of your app and device. For information on creating a new language model for your skill, please follow this link: https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/develop-skills-in-multiple-languages.html#add-a-language-to-an-existing-skill

-Option 2-
You can configure your account for a region that matches the language model you currently have set up for your skill. To do this, first make sure the device you're testing on is registered to your developer account, and then that it is set up for the correct language and location in its device settings. For actually configuring your account itself for that marketplace, you'll need to go through the retail Amazon site. Follow these steps:

- Navigate to https://www.amazon.com/
- Go to "Your Account" > "Your devices and content" > "Change your digital and device settings" > “Preferences”
- In "Preferences" click on the "Country/Region Settings" section
- If the country is not the same as the marketplace you need to test, change it to match